# Implementing "friendly" URLs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried some of the other answers I could find in here, but it didn't work out. It's really simple though.

I want

```
/page?id=PAGENAME
```

to be accessible AND redirected to

```
/PAGENAME
```

Can you help me?

EDIT:

It feels like my already messed-up .htaccess file needs to be included in here. I already have basic rewriting enabled, but this feature is needed for two other "special pages". In the requested solution above, I would therefore just replace "page" with the two pagenames (it's danish names, so I thought it was easier this way).

Currently I have this. If you have any improvements to it, it's appreciated - but I just want this to work with the requested solution aswell.

```
# Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Always on https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# remove trailing slash
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

#301 Redirect everything .php  to  non php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php?\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.+)\.php?$ http://MYURL.dk/$1 [R=301,L] 

#Hide the .php   from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 

#301 Redirect everything mistype after file extension -

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#301 Redirect everything to current url - 
RedirectMatch permanent /(.*).php/.* http://MYURL.dk/$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -D  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]  

#301 Redirect from non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.MYURL.dk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://MYURL.dk/$1 [R=301,L]

#301 redirect index.php to /
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
RewriteRule .* http://MYURL.dk/ [R=301,L]

#Deny access to songs
RewriteCond $1 !(loadmedia)\.php
RewriteRule ^songs/(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

Comment: "just replace `page` with the two pagenames" - I assume you mean `pagename`? There are certainly some things in your current .htaccess file that at least need "tidying". I don't think `-D` is a valid attribute? It looks like you should be checking for a directory, which is `-d` (lowercase). Also, the order of directives is important. External redirects should come _before_ internal rewrites. You have your canonical redirects at the end of your file - these should be at the top! Only include `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` once. Don't mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the URL in address bar should be like

`www.siteurl.com/pagename/` for seo purpose and then read this url from .htaccess using rule which gives this query string parameter values in your php file.

.htaccess rule can be like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /page?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: (+1) However, I would not end the URL in a slash, unless this specifically needs to _look like_ a directory.

Comment: Thanks. But exactly. I don't want the slash - and if I remove the slash from your codeline, I get an internal server error. Besides that, I can still access /page?id=ID now - I need that to be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to implement "friendly" (or "pretty") URLs, making the URLs more friendly for you users (search engines don't really mind what your URLs look like).

The first step is to change all your on-page links to use the new "friendly" URL. So, you links should all be of the form `/pagename` (not `/page?id=PAGENAME`).

Then, in `.htaccess`, you need to *internally rewrite* this "friendly" URL into the *real* URL that your server understands. This can be done using mod_rewrite. In the `.htaccess` file in your document root:

```
# Enable the rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the "friendly" URL back to the real URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ^([\w-]*) /page?id=$1 [L]
```

If the file does not exist (`!-f`) and does not contain the `id` URL param then *internally rewrite* the request from `/<pagename>` to `/page?id=<pagename>`. This assumes your `<pagename>` consists only of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`.

If this is a new site and the old URLs are not already indexed or referenced by external sites then you can stop here.

However, if you are changing an existing URL structure then you also need to *externally redirect* the real (ugly) URL to the "friendly" URL *before* the above *internal rewrite*. (This is actually what you are asking in your question.) In order to prevent a *rewrite loop* we can check against `%{THE_REQUEST}` (which does not change when the URL is rewritten).

```
# Redirect real URLs to "friendly" URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?id=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^page$ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK. Permanent redirects are cached by the browser so can make testing a problem.

So, in summary, with the above two parts shown together:

```
# Enable the rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect real URLs to "friendly" URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?id=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^page$ /%1? [R=302,L]

# Rewrite the "friendly" URL back to the real URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ([\w-]*) /page?id=$1 [L]
```

The order of directives is important. External redirects should nearly always come *before* internal rewrites.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> I want `/concept?id=NAME` to go to `/NAME` and `/studio?id=NAME` to go to `/NAME` - there's 5-10 different "pages" from both `concept` and `studio`. *[Corrected according to later comment]*

Since `id=NAME` maps to `/NAME` you can achieve all 10-20 redirects with just a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(NAME|foo|bar|baz|abc|def|ghi)
RewriteRule ^(concept|studio)$ /%1? [R,L]
```

This will redirect a URL such as `/studio?id=foo` to `/foo`.

As with all *external redirects* this should be one of the first rules in your .htaccess file.

Change `R` to `R=301` when you have tested that it is working OK.

To make this more "dynamic", ie. match any "NAME" then change the *CondPattern*, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\w-]*)
```

**UPDATE#2:**

If the path part of the URL (ie. `concept` or `studio`) is required then you can modify the `RewriteRule` substitution like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^(concept|studio)$ /$1/%1? [R,L]
```

Which will redirect `/concept?id=foo` to `/concept/foo`.

Or, to be completely "dynamic" (bearing in mind this will now capture *anything*):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /$1/%1? [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately it didn't work out, so I edited my question with further details. I think it might be something with my existing .htaccess.

Comment: So, to clarify, you need to redirect just 2 URLs (not a generic redirect) from `/page?id=<pagename1>` to `/<pagename1>` and the same for #2? You don't need the internal rewrite (that follows) because your application already handles this - is that correct? Note (as I commented above), external redirections must come before all your other directives at the very top of your .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I will check up on the errors in my current .htaccess - I got it some time ago from someone else, and it works - but yes, I'm not good at rewriting, so I use snippets most of the time. But to clarify: besides what the actual .htacces does, I want /concept?id=NAME to go to /name and /studio?id=NAME to go to /name - there's 5-10 different "pages" from both concept and studio. I couldn't make it work with your code above combined with my actual .htaccess (after I changed "page" -> "concept" / "studio").

Comment: I've included an update covering those (two) specific redirects.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, my bad - I meant that it should go to /NAME. Meaning: the ID-parameter should be the shorturl, so for example /concept?id=example should be shown and redirected to /example

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot! First of all, I would prefer if it could be dynamic (as in your first code) - and secondly it won't work. I guess I have taken enough of your time by now, so if you don't have any others suggestions, I will just find someone I can pay to fix my .htaccess file and make it work. Thanks again!

Comment: I've update my answer. Sorry, there was an error in the _CondPattern_ (there should not be a `!` prefix - that negates the pattern, which was required in the earlier part of the answer) - so give that a go. I've also included a more "dynamic" version.

Comment: I've noticed there's a problem with my requested solution here - it can't be done without doing a mess (and I guess that's the reason it doesn't work now either). I guess it has to be like /concept?id=NAME goes to /concept/NAME for example. Could you give a final answer on this? Then I will stop using up your time.

Comment: Well, whether this would work or not does depend on how the rest of your system works. Your system does need to be able to accept requests to a URL like `/NAME` and know exactly what to do with it. If you are redirecting from `/concept?id=NAME` _and_ `/studio?id=NAME` to `/NAME` (the same URL) then you are obviously losing some information. There is no way to reverse this action as there is now an ambiguity. If that is a problem then yes you will need to include `concept` or `studio` in the URL as well.

Comment: I need it to be made dynamically, and therefore it is a problem. For example i have other pages such as /booking - and if it is dynamically without /concept/ or /studio/ it would look for ex. /concept?id=booking as well - which is not what it should.

Comment: Updated the answer. This now captures the URL-path (providing it only consists of a single path segment and of restricted characters). I've also included a `?` on the end of the `RewiteRule` substitution to strip the query string from the redirected URL. fin.

Comment: Well, I'm glad for all your help, but it won't work. I don't know what is wrong, but no matter what I try, nothing happens to the URL's. But I'm sure other people can use your well-documented answers!

Comment: Update: your last solution did have an effect: it redirects all /concept?id=NAME and /studio?id=NAME to the front page. My other htaccess-code might be the reason.